# PHP - E_STRICT: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, strict

I see there are about a hundred different questions on here for `Creating default object from empty value`. None of them really seem to help with my issue.

I am assigning a child object of the same class in a method. This triggers the `Creating default object from empty value` error.

```
class myClass {


    function __construct($rootName, $allowHTML = false, $endTag = true) {
        $this->rootElement = $rootName;
        $this->elements = array();
        $this->attributes = array();
        $this->value = "";
        $this->allowHTML = $allowHTML;
        $this->endTag = $endTag;
        $this->styles = array();
        $this->childID = 0;
    }

    // ... OTHER METHODS HERE (ALL PROPERTIES DECLARED)

    function assignElement(&$theElement) {
        // Get the index.
        $index = count($this->elements);

        // Assign the element.
        $this->elements[$index] = $theElement;

        if (get_class($theElement) == get_class($this)) {
            $this->elements[$index]->childID = $index;
        }

        // Return the node.
        return $this->elements[$index];
    }
}
```

The error occurs on `$this->elements[$index]->childID = $index;`. How do I handle this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are passing `NULL` to the `assignElement`. `get_class` called with no arguments or null as argument, returns class of the object where it is defined, so your `if` conditions is true for null values. You should use `is_object` first.

Comment: This is what was happening. This is being used extensively in a large application and the variable being passed to it was occasionally undefined. Interesting that it gave me an E_STRICT error and not a NOTICE / undefined error.

Comment: Lack of NOTICE might be because of reference in your method.